# Have Multiple js Files in a Firefox addon that can have require method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am building an add-on that has multiple .js files that are associated with it many of which need the access to the `require()` function but when i use the require function in them i get the error that `require is not defined` but in the index file this works properly.

ie. I have a page in which i need access to the Browser's Local storage but when i try to use the simple-storage API it generates error.

CODE : `var storage_object = require("sdk/simple-storage");`

ERROR : `JPM undefined   Message: ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Is there a way by which i can have multiple files that have the require function and if not then how can I include the API's that are required in those `.js` files for proper functioning?

Answer (score 0):

Worker files can all use the require method :) Just have to `importScripts('resource://gre/modules/workers/require.js');` can read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts

Im not sure where the require.js documentation is on MDN.

Comment: the importScripts() is also not working since same error is generated "JPM undefined   Message: ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined". Also creating a new question for this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911802/importscripts-function-not-working-in-firfox-addon-code