# importScripts() function not working in Firefox addon code

Tags: javascript, include, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am building an add-on that has multiple .js files that are associated with it many of which need the access to the `require()` function but when i use the require function in them i get the error that require is not defined.used `importScripts()` to include the `require.js` file but the import scrips also generates error.

```
importScripts('resource://gre/modules/workers/require.js');
```

Also Used

```
self.importScripts('resource://gre/modules/workers/require.js');
```

The error generated is

```
JPM undefined   Message: ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined
```

And

```
JPM undefined   Message: ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined
```

*Need help to include multiple files that can have the access to the `require()` or `importScripts()` function.*

Comment: Mabe it helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500091/uncaught-referenceerror-importscripts-is-not-defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using the add-on SDK.

You can't use privileged code with all JS files, that includes require(). You can only use privileged code from your main.js script. Then use a content script/worker to communicate between the main script and the other script.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
let loader = Cc["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"]
               .getService(Ci.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);
loader.loadSubScript("chrome://marionette/content/simpletest.js");
```

Comment: Message: ReferenceError: Cc is not defined

Comment: @ejectamenta are you using addon sdk? If so you have to do `var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require('chrome')`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice example on using webworkers in addons, doesnt mention the importScripts function though :-(

[how to use webworkers in Mozilla addons](http://ikigomu.com/?p=248)

you could try adding them as normal using the importScripts function in your worker script but give full web urls to the worker scripts, FF doesn't seem to complain.

Comment: The workaround that I attempted in the end was to include all the external js files in a single web worker file that was loaded using var worker = new ChromeWorker("hello_world.js"), the call being made in the addon file (main.js). This however required such a complicated messaging system to be routed between the addon, content script, web worker and panel files that in the end I gave up on the webworker and used non blocking async call backs in the content script instead (also good for browser support).